# Получить переменные окружения после вызова subprocess.call

Tags: python

Из python скрипта вызывается (с помощью subprocess.call) другой скрипт (bat), в котором происходит установка переменной окружения.

`os.environ['PATH']` возвращает одинаковые данные до и после вызова subprocess.call, т.е. изменения переменных окружения не сохраняются после завершения работы внешнего скрипта.

Каким образом можно получить измененные переменные окружения?

Comment: Похожий вопрос про Unix https://stackoverflow.com/q/7040592/4279 (дочерний процесс окружение родителя не может поменять обычными способами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал так, вызывал команду set до и после батика, и сравнивал результат. Если надо только после, то код будет проще. Парсить результат команды set удобно парсером ini-файла, добавив в начало какое-то имя секции, в итоге код такой:

```
_CMD = "@echo off&echo [BEFORE]&set&echo *!*!*&{}&echo *!*!*&echo [AFTER]&set"
x = subprocess.check_output(_CMD.format(batFile),
                        shell=True).decode('cp1251')
# убираем средний элемент, в котором может быть вывод батика
x = ''.join(x.split('*!*!*')[::2])
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf.read_string(x)
da, db = dict(conf.items('AFTER')), dict(conf.items('BEFORE'))
```

Дальше надо сравнить словари `da` и `db` и узнать, какие переменные окружения были изменены в батике.